# F11 has suddenly become my screenshot key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, thumbnails

I'm new to using Ubuntu on a PC (but many many years ago, worked developing shell scripts in Unix for several years), and am going through the pain of setting up my first Ubuntu PC from scratch.  The PC will be specifically for video and image editing, and I'm using OpenShot for video.

I've been going through some tweaks to get thumbnails of my Nikon NEF stills and MP4 drone footage showing in 'Files' (Nautilus?), but I think that as a result of one of those tweaks, I now find that the F11 key, which used to switch OpenShot between window and full screen mode, is now a generic 'screenshot' taker (even outside of OpenShot, so I don't think it is anything I've done inside OpenShot).

Is there any way I can track back to identify when and how this occurred, and/or disable it so that F11 once more becomes simply F11?

Answer (score 2):

OK - If I knew how to do it, I'd put a shame faced emoji here...
The problem was absolutely nothing to do with any of the changes I have made to Ubuntu... I had somehow simply managed to 'lock' the Dell keyboard function keys on, and of course, the Fn action attached to the F11 key is - you guessed, PrtScr!  Just like Caps lock and Num lock, it appears my Dell keyboard has a Fn Lock key too.  Jeez - I've been exclusively using Dell laptops for the last 10 years at work - and never knew this!!!

Apologies all - stand down - nothing to see here :-)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. You'd be surprised how often the problem turns out to be 'Num Lock' or 'Caps Lock' or 'Fn Lock'. Especially on smaller keyboards. Good job figuring it out!